# What is more efficient? Initializing an array with an element or pushing an element to an empty array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

Is there any difference in terms of efficiency or is it a matter of preference and code readability?

For example if I have the two following options, which is more efficient?

Option 1:

```js
let test = [1];
```

Option 2:

```js
let test = [];
test.push(1);
```

Is one better than the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quickly testing in chrome's console:

```js
const t = performance.now(), tests = 1e9;
for(let i=0;i<tests;i++){
    let test = [1];
}
(performance.now() - t) / tests;
```

and

```js
const t = performance.now(), tests = 1e9;
for(let i=0;i<tests;i++){
    let test = [];
    test.push(1);
}
(performance.now() - t) / tests;
```

Initializing the array with a value takes approximately 7.5E⁻7 ms, while initializing an empty array and then using `array.push` takes around 1.925E⁻5. Initializing an array with a value is therefore significantly more performant than the second method.

In addition, the first method uses only 1 lines compared to the second method's 2 lines and is more readable.